# Assign ITGlue Contact to the Field using API powershell

Tags: powershell

I just want to assign the contacts to Application's field and another field with API Powershell but I don't know how to do it. could anyone help me?

Comment: Which contacts? Which field? What kind of API?

Comment: Contact from the company. Application Field . Rest API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [API documentation](https://api.itglue.com/developer/#flexible-asset-fields-show), there is no 'Application' resource type. Is it a custom resource, or a field on a different type of object? (what type?)

Try installing ITGlue's PowerShell wrapper module [**ITGlueAPI**](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ITGlueAPI/2.1.0) from the gallery (or [github link](https://github.com/itglue/powershellwrapper)):

```
Install-Module ITGlueAPI
Import-Module ITGlueAPI

# Check out all the available commands
Get-Command -Module ITGlueAPI

# initial setup:
Add-ITGlueBaseURI -base_uri 'http://myapi.gateway.example.com'
Add-ITGlueAPIKey -ApiKey 'your-key-here'

# Play around with these kinds of "Get-" commands which exist for each resource type:
# This is a good way to see how the data is formatted, and which fields exist per resource
Get-ITGlueFlexibleAssets 
Get-ITGlueContacts -organization_id 1234 -filter_first_name 'Foo' -sort 'first_name'

# To make changes, run similar "Set-" or "New-" commands with the updates in hash table format:
Set-ITGlueContacts -id 1234 -data @{
    location-id   = 795
    location-name = "San Francisco - HQ"
    field-name    = "Value"
}
```